# jqGrid getRegional error

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new to **jqGrid** and have been searching all over for the answer to my error.

What I am getting is:

> grid.formedit.js:1623 Uncaught TypeError: $.jgrid.getRegional is not a function

I have tried deleting the file and re-downloading the `grid.formedit.js` file to deleting the entire `jqgrid` package and re-installing it.  I have no idea how to fix it.  Hope someone can help.  Thanks!

Comment: did you include the locale file in i18n folder which is grid.locale-en.js?  I guess that is your problem.

Comment: add a reference tojquery.jqGrid.js  before the grid.formedit.js file. also share code on how the html looks.